# What to name a static "service" and where to place it in mvc solution

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, data-layers

I have a site structure as below:

- ProjectName.Core - entity framework, context, migrations, interfaces, extensions, enums
- ProjectName.Models - DTOS's only
- ProjectName.Repositories - Repositories only
- ProjectName.Services - services instanciated via ninject talking to repositories, automapper config
- ProjectName.Tests - speaks for itself
- ProjectName.Web.Customer - customer mvc site
- ProjectName.Web.Admin - Admin mvc site

My question:

Where would i put static "helper" classes such as below, and what should i call them?

- razor parser
- serializer/deserializer
- Email sender

It feels wrong calling them services and placing them together with the non static services, it's not intuitive to another developer...

Comment: if they are all not directly related to each other then may be "Utils"

Comment: @SamJones Did some of the answers help you here?

Comment: @ kayess Hi, yes. My purpose of this question was to get opinion and i don't see what's bad about that. There isn't always one correct answer as everyone has different experiences...

Comment: @SamJones of course, that's why we are here to give you answers and help eachother finding a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to address some ambiguities that I have noticed in the structure you have given in your question. By looking at your structure I'm assuming that you are trying to implement some sort of a [Onion](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)-/[Clean](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)-/[Hexagonal](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) architecture.

If you analyze the proposed architectural guidelines above it will become clear on the first sight that your Core project **should not** contain anything that is an infrastructural concern such as Entity Framework in your case. The core itself should only contain your business/domain models (along the business rules) and domain services.

Now lets just think for a second: how would the tests of Core look like if you are going to get EF or any other infrastructural concern into the picture? By testing Core you are usually trying to test *one* thing at once... so you don't have to mock out the rest of the dependencies.

Now to answer your question exactly, naming things is [not easy](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). I see that an answer recommends you to separate things from the rest of your application. Which in itself is good, but I wouldn't recommend it, it can become a [pain](https://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/07/16/project-anti-pattern-many-projects-in-a-visual-studio-solution-file/) if you use a lot of projects just for the sake of some good practices. An example reason I'm writing this is just think about the extra time to compile your solution with 3 extra projects for 3 different things?

My suggestion to organize these infrastructural concerns are as follows:

1. Create a project called `ProjectName.Infrastructure`

   - Add the each of the required NuGet packages/DLL references to the project
   - Create directories inside this project to organize your services
2. Add/create the implementations of your services here per directories you have create

   - Make sure each service implements an interface that you will get injected in your consumer classes
   - As a good advice separate these services by namespaces according to class names, eg.: `ProjectName.Infrastructure.EmailService`
3. The last part is to wire these infrastrucal concerns together via NInject

Final words: I hope you really don't need these services to be static at class level as you wrote. If so, you could still bind them that way via the proper NInject binding scope.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lumping all these unrelated concerns together, why not make it more granular?  Like this:

- ProjectName.Infrastructure.Serialization
- ProjectName.Infrastructure.Razor
- ProjectName.Infrastructure.Email

This way the semantics and structures are better and you're keeping the functionality separate.

Comment: So Serialization, Razor and Email would be classes and Infrastructure a project?

Comment: Yes, but you can get even more granular and make each one it's own project.

Comment: Well i'm liking the infrastructure project idea, then extensions, interfaces and enums could move into this and that way the only project referencing the core project would be the repository project. Just holding out to get some more opinions

Comment: I've used this for a long time.  The scope of responsibility needs to be managed, so sometimes several assemblies make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Services inside their own folder or Core.

I would not add another project just for static helpers.